# HttpActionContext storage location for life of request

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I have a HttpActionContext (WebApi) and am looking for a place to store a piece of information for the life of the request.  I found HttpActionContext.Request.[Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httprequestmessage.properties(v=vs.118).aspx) is this a good place, or is there a better place?

Comment: In what scenario are you working with here? whats your circumstance.

Comment: I have a library that receives a HttpActionContext and am looking to store a piece of information on that context for later use by the library, just within that request's lifetime on the server it is running on.  Sort of a cache.